# running babel-node commands on AWS elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Im trying to deploy an nodejs app to eb, all my code is using the new js features.

On my **package.json** I have start command:

```
scripts : {
    start: "babel-node bin/start.js"
}
```

this works fine on my localhost, when I deploy the app to EB, i get the error on the logs saying:

```
sh: babel-node: command not found
```

Can i run the babel-node command on a cloud server, or shall i compile my code before deployment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include babel-cli as a dependency in your package.json

You can do this by doing `npm i babel-cli`

**However**

That solves your problem but babel-node is not recommended for production use as stated in the [usage docs](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/#babel-node)